# Best way to get vertices of a mesh three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js so perhaps I am not going abut this optimally,

I have geometry which I create as follows,

```
const geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10,0);
```

I then apply a rotation to it

```
geo.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( Math.PI * 0.5 ) );
```

then I create a Mesh from it

```
const open = new THREE.Mesh( geo, materialNormal);
```

I then apply a bunch of operations to the mesh to position it correctly, as follows:

```
open.position.copy(v2(10,20);
open.position.z = 0.5*10

open.position.x -= 20
open.position.y -= 10
open.rotation.z = angle;
```

Now what is the best way to get the vertices of the mesh both before and after it's position is changed? I was surpised to discover that the vertices of a mesh are not in-built into three.js.

Any hints and code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're getting tripped-up by some semantics regarding three.js objects.

**1)** A `Mesh` does not have vertices. A `Mesh` contains references to `Geometry`/`BufferGeometry`, and `Material`(s). The vertices are contained in the `Mesh`'s `geometry` property/object.

**2)** You're using `PlaneBufferGeometry`, which means an implementation of a `BufferGeometry` object. `BufferGeometry` keeps its vertices in the `position` attribute (`mesh.geometry.attributes.position`). Keep in mind that the vertex order may be affected by the `index` property (`mesh.geometry.index`).

Now to your question, the geometric origin is also its parent `Mesh`'s origin, so your "before mesh transformation" vertex positions are exactly the same as when you created the mesh. Just read them out as-is.

To get the "after mesh transformation" vertex positions, you'll need to take each vertex, and convert it from the `Mesh`'s local space, into world space. Luckily, three.js has a convenient function to do this:

```
var tempVertex = new THREE.Vector3();
// set tempVertex based on information from mesh.geometry.attributes.position

mesh.localToWorld(tempVertex);
// tempVertex is converted from local coordinates into world coordinates,
// which is its "after mesh transformation" position
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example written by typescript.

It gets the grid's position in the world coordinate system.

```
    GetObjectVertices(obj: THREE.Object3D): { pts: Array<THREE.Vector3>, faces: Array<THREE.Face3> }
{
    let pts: Array<THREE.Vector3> = [];

    let rs = { pts: pts, faces: null };

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("geometry"))
    {
        let geo = obj["geometry"];
        if (geo instanceof THREE.Geometry)
        {
            for (let pt of geo.vertices)
            {
                pts.push(pt.clone().applyMatrix4(obj.matrix));
            }
            rs.faces = geo.faces;
        }
        else if (geo instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry)
        {
            let tempGeo = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geo);
            for (let pt of tempGeo.vertices)
            {
                pts.push(pt.applyMatrix4(obj.matrix));
            }
            rs.faces = tempGeo.faces;
            tempGeo.dispose();
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
```

or

```
if (geo instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry)
{
    let positions: Float32Array = geo.attributes["position"].array;
    let ptCout = positions.length / 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < ptCout; i++)
    {
        let p = new THREE.Vector3(positions[i * 3], positions[i * 3 + 1], positions[i * 3 + 2]);
    }
}
```