# How to get vertices of obj model object in Three.JS?

Tags: three.js, vertices, wavefront, objloader

After loading a .obj model in Three.js I am unable to find vertices data. Vertices data is needed to apply collision detection as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480717/1726743)

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('models/wall.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( node ) {
       if ( node.isMesh ) {
         console.log(node);
       }
    }); 
    scene.add( object );                
});
```

In mesh there is `geometry.attributes.position.array` but I am unable to find "vertices" anywhere in object.

Right now trying to convert `position.array` data to vertices but below code is not working, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317376/1726743) is pointing the problem correctly but I am unable to use it to solve the issue:

```
var tempVertex = new THREE.Vector3();
// set tempVertex based on information from mesh.geometry.attributes.position
mesh.localToWorld(tempVertex);
// tempVertex is converted from local coordinates into world coordinates,
// which is its "after mesh transformation" position
```

Comment: Can you please share your code that shows how you fill `tempVertex` with the `position` attribute data?

Answer (score 4):

`geometry.attributes.position.array` *IS* the vertices. Every three values makes up one vertex. You will also want to look at the `index` property (`geometry.index`), because that is a list of indices into the `position` array, defining the vertices that make up a shape. In the case of a `Mesh` defined as individual triangles, every three indices makes up one triangle. (Tri-strip data is slightly different, but the concept of referencing vertex values by the index is the same.)

You could alternately use the attribute convenience functions:

- [BufferAttribute.getX](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.getX)
- [BufferAttribute.getY](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.getY)
- [BufferAttribute.getZ](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.getZ)

These functions take the index into account. So if you want the first vertex of the first triangle (index = 0):

```js
let pos = geometry.attributes.position;
let vertex = new THREE.Vector3( pos.getX(0), pos.getY(0), pos.getZ(0) );
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
let pos = geometry.attributes.position.array;
let idx = geometry.index.array;
let size = geometry.attributes.position.itemSize;

let vertex = new THREE.Vector3( pos[(idx[0] * size) + 0], pos[(idx[0] * size) + 1], pos[(idx[0] * size) + 2] );
```

Once you have your vertex, *then* you can use `mesh.localToWorld` to convert the point to world-space.

Comment: `let pos = geometry.attributes.position; let vertex = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, 0);` will do the same thing, but in more convenient way. [reference](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.fromBufferAttribute)

Comment: @prisoner849 I guess I learned about yet another new convenience function today. :)